# C# - Combine multiple LINQ collections with same properties

Tags: c#, linq, list, union

Maybe it's late in the night, but I'm stumped here.  I'm trying to combine multiple lists with the same properties into one.  I thought that LINQ's .UNION would do the trick but I was mistaken.  Here's an example of a few of my lists:

```
LIST1 (report names):
Date      Name    Title         Product
02/01/13  Steve   Hello World   Report
02/05/13  Greg    Howdy         Report

LIST2 (song names):
Date      Name    Title         Product
01/01/13  John    Time          Song
01/05/13  Bob     Sorry         Song

LIST3 (games names):
Date      Name      Title         Product
12/01/12  Google    Bike Race     Game
12/05/12  Apple     Temple Run    Game
```

My class is very simple.  Here's what it looks like:

```
public class MyClass {
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

In case you're wondering, I used this LINQ query to get one of the above lists:

```
var finalList = Games
  .Select (s => new MyClass { 
    Date = (System.DateTime) s.Games.Creation_date,
    Name = s.Games.Last_name,
    Title = string.Format("{0} (Report)", s.Game.Headline),
    Product="Report"
  })
  ;
```

So far, it's pretty easy, but I want to combine all my lists into 1.  So, my final list should look like:

```
Date      Name    Title         Product
02/01/13  Steve   Hello World   Report
02/05/13  Greg    Howdy         Report
01/01/13  John    Time          Song
01/05/13  Bob     Sorry         Song
12/01/12  Google  Bike Race     Game
12/05/12  Apple   Temple Run    Game
```

I thought that a UNION command would do it:

```
var newList = List1.Union(List2).Union(List3);
```

But I'm not getting the desired output.

```
Date      Name    Title         Product
02/01/13  Steve   Hello World   Report
02/05/13  Greg    Howdy         Report
01/01/13  Bob     Time          Game
01/05/13  John    Sorry         Song
12/01/12  Google  Bike Race     Song
12/05/12  Apple   Temple Run    Game
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what's result you get when using Union?

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3);
```

You don't want to be using `Union` ( working or not) anyway as it does set union.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the AddRange command should look something like this

```
var FullList = list1.AddRange(list2).AddRange(list3);
```

or the fail safe way whould be

```
var FullList = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).ToList(); //Personally i would use this
```

or you also have

```
var FullList = new[] { list1, list2, list3 }.SelectMany(a => GetAllProducts(a)).ToList();
```